# AndroidStudio find in entire project option?

Tags: android-studio, find

Does Android studio has a way to search a whole project for some text?
Like web-storm's **find in project** feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click corresponding project(module) =>Find in Path
- Keyboard shortcut - Ctrl+Shift+F

Answer (score 0):

You can search everywhere with "**Double Shift**".

Check this https://plus.google.com/+ChrisLacy/posts/E2C3Yp3qqU9